# Leg curls and hamstring training in general

Tags: muscle, muscle-gain, muscle-mass

Simply put, out of all hamstring exercises like leg curls, deadlifts, good mornings, nordic curls and so on... which one builds more leg muscle?

Comment: You might find this useful. GHR vs leg curls: https://fitness.stackexchange.com/a/38862/7091

Answer (score 2):

For overall Hamstring developement you should atleast include one Deadlift variation (the Hamstrings are activated when straightening the hip) and one Leg Curl variation (one of the muscles only inserts at the knee, so to hit that you have to curl).

Answer (score 0):

Hip thrust, deadlifts and sumo squats are my favorites. It is hard to say which movement produces more muscle but it's supposed that compound movement develop more muscles

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong but isnt hip thurst more a glute exercise than a hamstring one?

Answer (score -3):

The best exercise to put muscle on the thigh is doing squats. It's the king of leg exercises. Leg curls and presses only work when you have already put mass on the legs. To get bigger legs, don't do anything but squats!

Comment: Squats mainly train the quads. The question is about hamstrings though.

Comment: squats are the king of the leg builders they work all leg muscles any informed trainer should know that!

Comment: Deads and Leg Curls are still more effective if you really want to hit them. Sure, Squats should be in your training program nontheless.